# OpenCV in Python can't scan through pixels

Tags: python, opencv, pixel

I'm stuck with a problem of the python wrapper for OpenCv.
I have this function that returns 1 if the number of black pixels is greater than treshold

```
def checkBlackPixels( img, threshold ):
    width     = img.width
    height    = img.height
    nchannels = img.nChannels
    step      = img.widthStep
    dimtot   = width * height
    data = img.imageData
    black = 0

    for i in range( 0, height ):
        for j in range( 0, width ):
            r = data[i*step + j*nchannels + 0]
            g = data[i*step + j*nchannels + 1]
            b = data[i*step + j*nchannels + 2]

     if r == 0 and g == 0 and b == 0:
         black = black + 1

     if black >= threshold * dimtot:
        return 1
     else:
        return 0
```

The loop (scan each pixel of a given image) works good when the input is an RGB
image...but if the input is a single channel image I get this error:

```
for j in range( width ):
TypeError: Nested sequences should have 2 or 3 dimensions
```

The input single channel image (called 'rg' in the next example) is taken from
an RGB image called 'src' processed with cvSplit and then cvAbsDiff

```
cvSplit( src, r, g, b, 'NULL' )
rg = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src), src.depth, 1 ) # R - G
cvAbsDiff( r, g, rg )
```

I've also already noticed that the problem comes from the difference image got from cvSplit...

Anyone can help me?
Thank you

Comment: I see nothing in your code that's a nested sequence, so the `TypeError: Nested sequences should have 2 or 3 dimensions` error message makes no sense.

Comment: That's the fact! However the trick suggested from carnieri works good..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of OpenCV and which Python wrapper are you using? I recommend using OpenCV 2.1 or 2.2 with the Python interface that comes with the library.

I also recommend that you avoid scanning pixels manually, and instead use the low-level functions provided by OpenCV (see the [Operations on Arrays](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/core_operations_on_arrays.html)  part of the OpenCV docs). That way will be less error-prone and *much* faster.

If you want to count the number of black pixels in a single-channel image or in a color image with the COI set (so that the color image is effectively treated as a single-channel one), you could use the function [CountNonZero](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/core_operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero):

```
def countBlackPixels(grayImg):
    (w,h) = cv.GetSize(grayImg)
    size = w * h
    return size - cv.CountNonZero(grayImg)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I spent all the night on the OpenCv docs, but the only function that I overlooked it's CountNonZero...
It's perfect. Thank you again

Answer (score 5):

`widthStep` and `imageData` are no longer valid attributes for IplImage object. Thus, the correct way to loop through each pixel and grabbing its color value would be

```
for i in range(0, height):
    for j in range(0, width):

        pixel_value = cv.Get2D(img, i, j)
        # Since OpenCV loads color images in BGR, not RGB
        b = pixel_value[0]
        g = pixel_value[1]
        r = pixel_value[2]

        #  cv.Set2D(result, i, j, value)
        #  ^ to store results of per-pixel
        #    operations at (i, j) in 'result' image
```

Hope you find this useful.