# OpenCV - Counting number of black pixels

Tags: c, opencv, optimization, image-processing

I have a binary image. Within a certain region of interest, I need to count the number of black pixels. There is always the way of looping through the pixels and counting them, but I'm looking for a more efficient method as I need to do it real-time.

I found a way to count the number of nonzero pixels(using cvCountNonZero()). Is there any such equivalent function for counting zero pixels (there doesn't seem to be as far as I've seen)? If not, what is the most efficient way to count the black pixels?

Comment: Couldn't you just subtract the number of nonzero pixels from the total number of pixels in the region?

Comment: Check answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695691/opencv-in-python-cant-scan-through-pixels

Comment: Yes, I've done that, but as my images usually have a very low concentration of black pixels and my purpose is to just check for the presence of any black pixel, I thought counting black pixels would be better. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the number of *zero pixels* could be seen as:

```
int TotalNumberOfPixels = width * height;
int ZeroPixels = TotalNumberOfPixels - cvCountNonZero(cv_image);
```

Comment: OpenCV >2.4 C++ implementations should probably use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19167645/616644) answer.  It's pretty much this answer but using the newer C++ interface.