# Count the black pixels using OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I'm working in `opencv 2.4.0` and `C++`

I'm trying to do an exercise that says I should load an RGB image, convert it to gray scale and save the new image. The next step is to make the grayscale image into a binary image and store that image. This much I have working.

My problem is in counting the amount of black pixels in the binary image.

So far I've searched the web and looked in the book. The method that I've found that seems the most useful is.

```
int TotalNumberOfPixels = width * height;
int ZeroPixels = TotalNumberOfPixels - cvCountNonZero(cv_image);
```

But I don't know how to store these values and use them in `cvCountNonZero()`.  When I pass the the image I want counted from to this function I get an error.

```
int main()
{
    Mat rgbImage, grayImage, resizedImage, bwImage, result;

    rgbImage = imread("C:/MeBGR.jpg");
    cvtColor(rgbImage, grayImage, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    resize(grayImage, resizedImage, Size(grayImage.cols/3,grayImage.rows/4),
           0, 0, INTER_LINEAR);

    imwrite("C:/Jakob/Gray_Image.jpg", resizedImage);
    bwImage = imread("C:/Jakob/Gray_Image.jpg");
    threshold(bwImage, bwImage, 120, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    imwrite("C:/Jakob/Binary_Image.jpg", bwImage);
    imshow("Original", rgbImage);
    imshow("Resized", resizedImage);
    imshow("Resized Binary", bwImage);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

So far this code is very basic but it does what it's supposed to for now. Some adjustments will be made later to clean it up :)

Comment: You need to provide what the error you received is. Is it a compile error? A runtime error? etc?

Comment: Are you doing this in `C` or `C++`:   `cvCountNonZero` is `C` function. `C++` is `countNonZero`... http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`countNonZero`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) to count the number of pixels that are not black (>0) in an image. If you want to count the number of black (==0) pixels, you need to subtract the number of pixels that are not black from the number of pixels in the image (the image width * height).

This code should work:

```
int TotalNumberOfPixels = bwImage.rows * bwImage.cols;
int ZeroPixels = TotalNumberOfPixels - countNonZero(bwImage);
cout<<"The number of pixels that are zero is "<<ZeroPixels<<endl;
```

Comment: Just curious, so is the issue primarily that his TotalNumberOfPixels was wrong, or that he was mixing C & C++ api's together?

Comment: I think the issue was that you were mixing C and C++. You are working with the C++ interface, and you use Mat as the datatype for an image. Mat does not have `width` and `height` members, it has `rows` and `cols`. Also, you were probably using the C API function `cvCountNonZero` with a `Mat` parameter, which is used in the C++ API.

Comment: When i enter that code it gives me an unhandled exception: Exception at memory location 0x0033F890.

It also wrote something to the console/window:
OpenCV Error: Assertion fialed <src.channels<> == 1 & func !=0> in unknown function, file c:\slave\builds\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\core\src\stat.cpp, line496

I tried to use the code you provided in a new project where i just load the image and apply your code. Same error.

Comment: Maybe i got a problem with my installation? Im using Visual Studio if that has anything to do with it.

And yea i mixed up some c and c++ stuff. Hehe.

Comment: @Jakob: You probably tried to use `countNonZero` on a color image (3 channels). `countNonZero` only works on grayscale images (single channel). Modify this line in your code: `bwImage = imread("C:/Jakob/Gray_Image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);`

Comment: Wuuu. Thank you so much Ove :)

It seems to work now.

What confused me/my mistake was that i didn't know about the `countNonZero` on a color image part. I assumed that when i saved the binary image it would open in single channel. And also i was trying to get the width and height as you also said in your reply.

Comment: why not use `countNonZero(bwImage==0)` to count zero pixels?

Comment: I agree with @zhangxaochen.  Why don't you invert the image prior to use `countNonZero`?

Comment: @rayryeng and zhangxaochen: If your method works, then use whatever is best for you. In my tests, my method is faster. Here is the code I used to benchmark: http://codepad.org/dlEYi6ZQ